# How to set .val() in this get filter in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch multiple user from API and in select option I am able to select multiple user, but I cannot fetch data. So how to set `.val() in const select =..` option? I am trying to fetch, but that process I did I can only fetch one data and in my API I can select user like `user= 1,2,3,4`, so I want also in react js. So please help me.

```
getData = async e => {
    try {
      // alert("Your favorite flavor is: " + this.state.value);
      const edd = e.target.elements.edd.value;
      const selectOptions = e.target.elements.selectOptions.value; // And I want to Select .() in this handler that i can fetch multiple user
      const modee = e.target.elements.modee.value;
      const from = e.target.elements.from.value;
      const to = e.target.elements.to.value;
      e.preventDefault();
      const res = await fetch(
        `${config.apiUrl.report}?date__lte=${to}&date__gte=${from}&user=${selectOptions}&mode=${modee}&electric_bike=${edd}`
      );
      const movies = await res.json();
      console.log(movies);
      this.setState({
        movies
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to allow the user to select multiple options, then join their values with commas to pass into the API parameters?

If you give the HTML select element the `multiple` attribute, the user will be able to select multiple options by holding shift or command/ctrl while selecting the options. From there, you need to iterate over all options and make note of whichever are selected to join them into a string. Something like this:

```
const selections = [...e.target.elements.selectOptions.options].filter(opt => opt.selected);
const selectedValues = selections.map(opt => opt.value);
const selectedString = selectedValues.join(',');
```

You can of course combine these into one or two lines, I just added all the intermediate values to make the process clear for demonstration purposes :)